# google cloud sql redmine mysql not responding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine, google-cloud-sql

I've been trying to set up a Redmine on google compute engine with the mysql 5.5 database hosted on google cloud sql (d1, 512mb of ram, always-on, europe, package-billed).

Unfortunately, Redmine stops responding (really stops, I set the timeout to 1hour and nothing happens) to requests after a few minutes. Using newrelic I found out that it's database-related - ActiveRecord seems to have some problems with the database ..

In order to find out if the problems are really related to the cloud sql database, I set up a new database on my own server and it's working fine since then. So there definitely is an issue with the cloud sql database and redmine/ruby.

Does anyone have an idea what I can try to solve the problem?

Best,
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCE idle connections are closed automatically after 10 minutes as explained in [1]. As you are connecting to CloudSQL from a GCE instance, this is most likely the cause for your issue.

Additionally, take into account Cloud SQL instances can go down and come back anytime due to maintenances and connections must be managed accordingly. Checking the CloudSQL instance operation list would confirm this. Hope this helps.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/gce-access